# centering image popup using when mouse over script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found the mouse over script bellow here on this site and it works really well and easy to use. The only downside of it is where it places the image. The image is placed relevant to the courser and follows it as the mouse is moved.

Question: Is it possible to get the image to appear centered on the visible screen and fixed there? ( Fixed in position as long as the mouse is over the text.)

The script

```
    var offsetX = 180;
    var offsetY = -25;
    $('a').hover(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');    
$('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" />')
.css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
.css('left', e.pageX + offsetX)
.appendTo('body');
}, function() {
$('#largeImage').remove();
});

$('a').mousemove(function(e) {
$("#largeImage").css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
});
```

This is the CSS style

```
    #largeImage {
position:absolute;
padding: .5em;
background: #e3e3e3;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
color:#aa1416;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="largeImage">
    <li><h2><a id="item1"href="images/image6a.png">Breakfast Plates .....</a></h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').hover(function(e) {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" />')
    .appendTo('body');
}, function() {
  $('#largeImage').remove();
});

$('a').mousemove(function(e) {});
```

```css
#largeImage {
  position: fixed;
  padding: .5em;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
  color: #aa1416;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="largeImage">
  <li>
    <h2><a id="item1"href="images/image6a.png">Breakfast Plates .....</a></h2>
</div>
```